# What property does the function hold which values equal the complex conjugate of the function with argument with opposite sign?$X(-\nu)=X^*(\nu)?$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, terminology

I know that if

$$X(-\omega) = X(\omega),$$

then the function $X$ is even.

[Here](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw09.pdf) I read that

> In general, if a signal $x(t)$ is real, then $$X(-\omega) = X^*(\omega).$$

What is the name of this property of $X$?

Comment: Feel free to edit the question to have it more compact with the same meaning if you can.

Comment: [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_function)?

Comment: Yep, that seems good. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a function is [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_function).